# PII data to Google Analytics as Custom Dimension

Tags: google-analytics

Can we send user name, email, etc to GA for tracking user behavior as custom dimension variables to Google analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send PII to Google Analytics like explicit email. Google could close your Account and delete all data.

Understanding PII in Google's contracts and policies:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7686480

You can use hash like SHA256 + salt to encrypt personal information, then you can send it to Google Analytics.